# How to bind the value of HTML element in JS file of Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have a value for HTMl element,button to be specific. I want to get this value to .js file to send the value to back end.

How can I achieve it?

```
<div class="col-md-1">
            <button value="1" ng-model="Month" ng-click="report()"
                class="btn btn-warning btn-sm  row-line-height"
                style="float: right; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-right: 20%; font-size: 9px"
                ng-show="Report">Report</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: The default values to send (1 in this case) have no reason to be defined in the HTML template. just hard-code it in the JS code instead of hard-coding it in the template. Or, if you have several such buttons, all calling report() with a different value, then it should be `ng-click="report(1)"`, and the report function should of course take the value as argument.

Comment: @ JB Nizet,I have many more buttons like this,each having a different values

Comment: Then re-read my comment (which I have edited while you reacted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used an ng-model on a button, and I'm not entirely certain that it works that way.  If it does you should have the value available in 'Month' on your controller.  If you just need the value in the report() method, pass it in as an argument. `ng-click="report(1)"`

Comment: Okay. Say I've used ng-model on a div and also value,is it not possible to get the value in controller by giving $scope.Month.value ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using `value` on a div or a button.  Isn't that generally reserved for inputs?  I think the problem might be with your approach here.  What is it that you're trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: ..reading your new comment, it seems like maybe you want each button to pass the a value to the `report()` method.  If that's the case you should pass it as an argument, as noted above.